# How to call NSBeep from Delphi

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I'm looking for a MessageBeep replacement on the OS X. It seems that the proper function to call would be [NSBeep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408835/4997) but it is not supported by XE2 RTL.

How do I call NSBeep from Delphi application?

Comment: What about to use the [`Beep`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Beep) instead ? However I have no idea what they mean with the note *On MAC OS the Beep routine has limited functionality*, does it mean it does less than *beep* :-) ?

Comment: In my case this would probably be enough but I would like to learn how to properly add my own imports on OS X.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a plain C function:

```
procedure NSBeep; cdecl;
  external '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/AppKit' name '_NSBeep';
```

Comment: Thanks! I almost got it but I was missing the last '/AppKit' in the external and it didn't work.