# OutputDebugString() with Delphi for MacOS

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, nslog, firemonkey, outputdebugstring

Is there an NSLog declaration in the Delphi OSX units. I failed to find a substitude for OutputDebugString in a Firemonkey application.

The final solution looks like this:

```
/// <remarks>
/// Output debug string. Output debug string can be seen in Delphi
/// View|Debug Windows|Event Log or with 3-rd party programs such as
/// dbgview.exe from SysInternals (www.sysinternals.com)
/// </remarks>
procedure ODS(const Text: string);
begin
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405447/outputdebugstring-with-delphi-for-macosunit unt_Debug;
  Log.d(Text);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF LINUX}
  __write(stderr, AText, Length(AText));
  __write(stderr, EOL, Length(EOL));
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  OutputDebugString(PWideChar(Text));
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Based on [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10287822/960757), wouldn't be possible to import the `NSLog` procedure like [`shown here`](http://community.freepascal.org:10000/bboards/message?message_id=397175&forum_id=24111) at point 9 ? It's just a wild guess, I have absolutely nothing to do with OSX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firemonkey, the portable way to display a message in the Event Log is [Log.d](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.Log.d):

```
    uses FMX.Types;

    ...

    Log.d('debugging');
```

I think it is available from [XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/FMX.Types.Log.d) onwards.